# Significance of current and previous directories under Hadoop/Datanode directories

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

1. What is the significance of current and previous directories under Hadoop/Datanode directories? How hadoop uses them?
2. I've a /current directory under path /hadoop/datanode on all the disks of local filesystem.

It contains the following:

> subdirX
>
> blk_X.meta
>
> blk_X

SubdirX folders contains subdirectories and sub-subdirectories and a number of blocks & their meta files. What is their significance and how are they stored? How hdfs decides to create these subdirectories?

Any documention on these would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for http://hortonworks.com/blog/hdfs-metadata-directories-explained/, It should be able to answer all your queries related to the directory structuring.
If you have any queries you can update your question for same.